# Get value from ajax in input field

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to create ajax search where the user type their code to search school and university name. but I could not pass this two value to my input field.

**html**

```
<input name="code" id="search" value="">
<input name="school" value="" type="text">
<input name="uni" value="" type="text">
```

**ajax**

```
 $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $value=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'get',
                    url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                    data:{'search':$value},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('input[name="school"]').val(data);
                        $('input[name="uni"]').val(data); //does'nt work
                    }
            });  
        });
```

**controller**

```
public function search(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $output="";
            $code=Model::where('code','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
            if($code){
                foreach ($code as $key => $code) {
                    $output.= 
                    $code->school;
                    $code->uni;
               }
               return Response($output);
            }
        }

    }
```

The school name shows correctly but the university name does not come. How can I do it? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the concatenation for university. If I am not wrong, this should work:

```
$output.= $code->school;
$output.= $code->uni;
```

Instead try that:

```
public function search(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $output= array();
            $code=Model::where('code','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
            if($code){
                foreach ($code as $key => $code) {
                    $output['school'] = $code->school;
                    $output['uni'] = $code->uni;
               }
               return Response($output);
            }
        }

    }

 $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $value=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'get',
                    url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                    data:{'search':$value},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('input[name="school"]').val(data.school);
                        $('input[name="uni"]').val(data.uni);
                    }
            });  
        });
```

Comment: yeah I tried this one. but this two values shows both  in two input field. for exp:  the university input field shows both school and university name both @user3282898

Comment: Return the data as an array not a concatenate string. I think that's why the two values are shown in the input fields. The return array should be something like that:
`$output = array('school' => 'school_name', 'uni' => 'uni_name');`

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have a try with this one. 
`console.log(data)` to know what information is present and how they should be passed in the `.val()`.